# Control is not going in template file

Tags: theming

I am including a template file from hook_theme.

```
function my_module_theme() {

  return array(
    'my_entity' => array(
      'variables' => array('title' => NULL, 'body' => NULL),
      'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module') . '/templates',
      'template' => 'my_entity'
    ),
  );
}
```

this is the code and i don't know why control is not going in template file.
Note:- Cache flushed.

Comment: Template file name should be 'my-entity'.

Comment: its that only.i have updated the question

Comment: Are you using Drupal 6 or Drupal 7?

Comment: For hook functions always clear the cache.

Comment: @harshal cache cleared.
 drupal 7

Comment: pls update as said by @Jayendra Kainthola 'template' => 'my-entity'